# Coding a Monthly archive in coldfusion

Tags: sql, coldfusion

In my SQL Database I have a Column called Date in General Date Format (1/1/2001 12:35:05AM).

How within a page archive will I show the number of posts monthly and by year posted.

I can understand that I need to somehow count each post for each month then somehow have it separate the year based off the counting.

I really cannot leave a code example, since I'm baffled how this will work.

```
<div  class="leftbracketholder">

<div class="leftboxes">
  <li><A Href="Fish.com">0</a></li>


 </div>
```

`<cfquery name="Archive" datasource="FishingRackets">
Select Date
From Posts
</cfquery>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me see if I can help shed light on your issue.

First you have a few things going on so lets simplify them.

You are generating a report for viewing and in that report you want to show:

Totals by month per year, correct? So we need a good SQL select statement.

Then you are using the cfquery to send the query to the DB and return the data for use.

Where then you need to output that data in a meaningful way using cfoutput.

So lets use some hypotheticals (based on the limited code provided).

The SQL: Select Date From Posts is not going to be useful to you (disclaimer: I don't know your specific SQL variety so this is a dumbed down untested example provided to get you thinking).

You said you have a regular date field.  I am assuming this is a datetime field.

So one thing you can do is create a count by datetime and make it by month and year.

```
select month(dateField) as month, year(dateField) as year 
  from posts 
 order by month, year
```

Next lets adjust your cfquery stuff...

```
<cfquery name="archive" datasource="fishingRackets">
select month(dateField) as month, year(dateField) as year 
  from posts 
 order by month, year
</cfquery>
```

Now lets take that div stuff and organize it under a cfoutput. Note that cfoutput loops over the data and does one better it groups things for you.

So if you need to go by month year you can do it a few ways:

```
<div>

<cfoutput query="archive" group="year">
<h2>#year#</h2>

<cfoutput>
<div>
<li><a href="yourlinkhere.com/somepage.cfm?month=#month#&year=#year#">#month#/#year#</a></li>
</div>
</cfoutput>

<cfoutput>
</div>
```

You see that cfoutput inside another cfoutput? That is what determines the grouping.

BUT! you are only half done the link to the next page will get you a refined query like this:

(And this is just for example so Coldfusion Gurus go easy).

In the link:

```
yourlinkhere.com/somepage.cfm?month=#month#&year=#year#
```

You can grab those URL variables and fix the SQL like this:

```
<cfquery name="archive" datasource="fishingRackets">
select month(dateField) as month, year(dateField) as year 
  from posts 
 WHERE DATEPART(mm, Date) = #url.month# 
   AND DATEPART(yyyy, Date) = #url.year#
 order by month, year
</cfquery>
```

(the query above is not exact and it may not work at all.  But the idea here is that you go to your link and you refine down the query to just the results in the year and the month. and dump them out to the page (if you needed to go this far).

More on cfquery/cfoutput/and SQL + dates

[Google-fu on datetime month/year group select etc.](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql%20datetime%20just%20month%20and%20year&oq=datetime%20sql%20month%20and%20year&month%20and%20year%20group%20by)

[cfquery stuff](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_p-q_17.html)

[See this post on another type of group example (basically what I created above with more detail).](http://www.richarddavies.us/archives/2007/03/cfoutput_group_tip.php)

[See more on your handy-dandy cfoutput tag here.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_m-o_16.html)

Last thoughts: get to know SQL, cfquery and cfoutput, they are the bread-and-butter/ meat-and-potato / mother-of-all coldfusion 'things' and 'stuff'. (in other words, it's where we all start and cut our coldfusion teeth).

This should be sufficient enough to get you started. Good luck!

Comment: I have pasted it into my page. and ended up with Error Executing Database Query.

`[Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2.` I have tried changing the alias to "months" and "years" because it looks like year and month are reserved but that didn't change the error.

Comment: Note that I said I don't know what your SQL flavor is: you just said a SQL database...Is it MySQL or SQL Server? etc.

Comment: Ah-ha...Access...Ok this is a different bird (like I said the SQL won't be right).  So here is what I recommend.  In access you can use the GUI interface to build simple queries.  You can filter those queries like I am doing and like the poster below has done.  But you are going to need to dig into your date types.  What is available, what is allowed and look at those specific SQL examples. You may be luck and find Coldfusion cfquery MSAccess date filtering examples.

Comment: Functions in the where clause slow down performance.  Where date >= startdate and date < the day after end date will run faster.

Answer (score 0):

This query will get you what you're looking for. From there it should be easy to output that to the page by looping through the query.

```
SELECT month(date) as month, year(date) as year, count(post_id) as posts
FROM posts
WHERE date BETWEEN <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="startDate"> 
  AND <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="endDate">
GROUP BY month(date), year(date)
ORDER BY year, month
```

Comment: I intentionally skipped the parameterization sqltypes.  This guy is starting with 'the basics' and I didn't want to confuse him with the 'best practices'. Your query looks great though...

Comment: "the basics" should include "best practices". Plus your suggestions shouldn't be "wrong", and it's pretty much wrong to hard-code data values into an SQL statement.

Comment: If the date field includes a time component, the keyword "between" could cause you to miss some records.